# Wordpress: Strange rewrite issue, /randomstring/categoryname works

Tags: wordpress

Bit of background, we manage a network of 25 different WP sites that all run off the same codebase. Recently we had an SEO analyst join and he noticed a couple of the sites had weird 404 issues, for URLs like this:

```
**/category/featured-article/ryan-mcnamara-new-different/news/page/2/**
```

So I disabled all plugins and hooks, tried on a fresh install, and this stuff is still happening. Turns out it only happens the site's permalink structure ends in .html. So I delved into the rewrite code and turns out this is whats happening for the URL: `**/category/featured-article/ryan-mcnamara-new-different/news**`

- If the permalink structure is `**/%category%/%postname%/**`, then of the
  available rewrite rules (`$wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules()`) then this rule
  is matched:  `**(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$**`, causing a 404 as expected.
- If the permalink structure is `**/%category%/%postname%.html**`, then this
  rule is matched: `**(.+?)/?$**`, which maps to
  `**index.php?category_name=$matches[1]**`, hence why the category is
  rendered When users/bots find these category pages and click the
  pagination links they get taken to
  `**/category/featured-article/ryan-mcnamara-new-different/news/page/2/**`, which
  causes a 404.

The first question is how are people finding these pages in the first place, which is an issue I can deal with. The question for this forum is this a bug with the rewrites WP has as default OR should the paginate_links function be smarter about creating pagination URLs? Has anybody ever seen this problem before?

Caveats: No, I can't force all sites to drop the .html, and no I don't have the ability to change core WP code for this problem